# Android: Receiver not getting invoked and Service is not getting started

Tags: android

I am working on my first Android's service ever and I want it to start when the OS starts. I put some print outs in the code to detect and make sure that the Receiver/Service gets invoked. Well, I don't see it in the logcat. Here is the code and I think I did everything right? Or not?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.denniss"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:process=":random_number_background"
                 android:name=".RandomNumberService"
                 android:label="Random Number Service"/>
        <receiver android:name="RandomNumberBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:process=":random_number_background">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The service that is supposed to generate random number =)

```
package com.denniss;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.IBinder;

    public class RandomNumberService extends Service{

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

The broadcast receiver

```
package com.denniss;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class RandomNumberBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("**************************************************");
        System.out.println("RandomNumberBroadcastReceiver onReceive is called!");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, RandomNumberService.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times here, a search would have turned up the answers below about the missing permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the required permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 2):

a) Your `AndroidManifest.xml` must contain

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

b) Your app must have been started once if your app runs on Honeycomb (Android 3.1.x) or above. Otherwise your app is not considered active and won't receive any broadcasts.